# Cart with fix amount - variable products

Tags: checkout, cart, totals

we want to create a "special" Shop where we offer 50€ packages of our products. Customers can choose variable products which they want to put in their package. But only up to the total amount of 50€. 
For this max value I found an extension: [Magento Maximum Allowed Order Amount](http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-maximum-allowed-order-amount/)

The problem is a cart amount <50€. The customers should have the freedom to complete the order even if the amount is lower. But in this case I want to charge the 50€ anyway ;)

Any ideas, suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It's not completely clear what you want to achieve, but I try to help anyway:

One way is to use configurable product / custom options using attribute / option *quantity*. This allow you to determine static price 50€. It's relatively simple having only one downside -- no way to manage inventory.

Another way is to use bundles. It's somewhat similar, slightly more complicated, but  allows you to manage inventory as well.